React-hook-form + Yup + Internationalised labels
I have a package with many Yup object schemas that define validation rules, but don't provide labels on their properties because the package is also language agnostic.
Then I have an app that uses the said package and has react-hook-form forms, where I consume these schemas, but I need to bind labels to those validation rules, so that errors are displayed correctly and in the correct language set by the app.
How to avoid label duplication
I know I can manually do
existingSchema.shape({
    someProp: existingSchema.fields.someProp.label('Some property'),
    ...
})
// and
<TextField label="Some property" />

which would reuse validation rules for each field and add their labels, but then again I would have to set the same labels again on the form fields which seems kindda unnecessary code duplication.
I would like to avoid this, so that I would only call the yupResolver with label-less schema and provide labels on the fields and resolver would bind the two. I know that yupResolver doesn't have this capability per se, so I'm aware I'd have to write my own resolver that would do the trick for me.
Could also be with some intermediary class that would have the Record<string, string> for model prop names and labels and use the two with resolver and form fields.
Has anybody done something similar or have an idea how to approach this automated validation schema extender?
I haven't found anything useful on the interwebs.
